# Centering Objects to Multiple Artboards with Illustrator Script

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator

Assume, I have 5x5 25 artboards in Illustrator with different letters on each. I want them to be centered on each artboard. Is there a script for it?
I have checked but generally they are all working for one artboard at once.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested script?

Comment: That's great Yuri,
Thank you very very much, working like a charm!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for (var i=0; i<doc.artboards.length; i++) {
    app.selection = null;
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(i);
    doc.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard();
    to_center(doc.artboards[i], app.selection[0]);
    app.selection = null;
}

function to_center(artboard, item){
    var artboard_x = artboard.artboardRect[0] + artboard.artboardRect[2];
    var artboard_y = artboard.artboardRect[1] + artboard.artboardRect[3];
    var x = (artboard_x - item.width)/2;
    var y = (artboard_y + item.height)/2;
    item.position = [x, y];
}
```

The script puts a first item on every artboard in the middle of the artboard.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]